# Django form missing fields

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to get a simple form working. Oddly, other forms I wrote in this app are working fine, but this one wont show the fields. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Here are the files

**views.py:**

```
def newnote(request, record_id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NoteForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tracker/all/')
else:
    form = NoteForm()
return render(request, 'tracker/noteform.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Note(models.Model):
record = models.ForeignKey(Record, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
note_text = models.CharField('Notes', max_length=2000)
note_date = models.DateField('Date Entered')
```

**forms.py**

```
class NoteForm(forms.Form):
class Meta:
    model = Note
    fields = ['note_text',
              'note_date'
             ]
```

**template (noteform.html)**

```
<form action="/tracker/newnote/" method="post">  
<div id="fields">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

One other note, I have commented out the div id called "fields", to rule out CSS as the issue.

Comment: The usual way of displaying a form is `{{ form.as_p }}` or `{{ form.as_table }}`.  Does just plain `{{ form }}` even work?

Comment: @JohnGordon as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#outputting-forms-as-html) show, outputting a form is the same as calling its `as_table` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is based on `form.Form`, which doesn't know anything about models, doesn't expect a Meta class, and expects all its fields to be declared manually - since you have not declared any fields, nothing will show on the template.

It should inherit `forms.ModelForm` instead.

Comment: class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
This did the trick! I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer lets me.